# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: setBackground()

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-framelayout

In my app I'm trying to set a Bitmap Image to `FrameLayout`, where the image came from `SQLite` database. I'm decoding that image converting it into `Drawable` and then setting it as background to `FrameLayout` but it gives me Error like `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.FrameLayout.setBackground()`

```
    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream2= new ByteArrayInputStream(cardbackground);
Bitmap Imagebackground = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream2);
Drawable imagebakground=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),Imagebackground);
framelayout.setBackground(imagebakground);
```

I'm using,,

```
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

Comment: What is `f` variable?

Comment: Its a framelayout object..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setBackground()` method was added into API level 16. use `setBackgroundDrawable()` instead....

```
    Drawable imagebakground = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),Imagebackground);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        framelayout.setBackground(imagebakground);
    } else {
        frameLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(imagebakground);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`setBackground()` is available from API Level 16, so having minSdkVersion set to 14 does not help. The device where you are testing it, has to be at least that api level

Answer (score 2):

Set `Bitmap` as `BackgroundDrawable` to your `Layout` instead of `setBackground()`

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
  your_layout.setBackground(...);
 else
  your_layout.setBackgroundDrawable(...);
```

It's becoz `setBackground()` is available from API Level 16